# How to create log file from one file to another file during importing function

Tags: python

```
main.py
import logging
import datetime
from test1 import process
def log_file():
    log_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    log_name = '/home/flock/PycharmProjects/sample1/log_basics/' + log_day + '_main_rentals_log.log'
    return log_name

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file(), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

def process2(abc):
    print("Going to check: "+str(abc))
    logging.info("Going to check test1: "+str(abc))
    ans = process(abc)
    print(ans)

abc = "68485"
process2(abc)

test1.py
import logging
import datetime
def log_file():
    log_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    log_name = '/home/flock/PycharmProjects/sample1/log_basics/' + log_day + '_test1_rentals_log.log'
    return log_name

def process(abc):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file(), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
    print("This is test1: "+str(abc))
    logging.info("This is test1: "+str(abc))
    return "Finished"
```

Is there any solution to log 2024-03-11 12:21:30,354:INFO:This is test1: 68485 to the test1_rentals_log.log instead it is creatin the log on the main python file.